# Can't connect web3 with ganache - python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, smartcontracts, web3py, ganache

```
import web3, solc,json

from web3.contract import ConciseContract

from web3 import Web3,HTTPProvider

from web3.auto.gethdev import w3

ganache_url="HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"

con=Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

con.isConnected()

*False*
```

I am trying to connect to ganache from google colab using web. The problem is, web3 is never connected to the ganache server. I would like to know if it is a problem of using GoogleColab to connect to ganache on my PC or it is a code problem.

I saw a lot of tutorials uising the command line and running it there in python scripts, outside a enviroment as googleColab or Jupyter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ganache is a Node.js package installed via npm - usually needs installing manually by `npm install -g ganache-cli`

This won't be installed in colab by default.

I've had success using web3.py in colab by using an Alchemy RPC node like this:

```
w3 = web3.Web3(web3.HTTPProvider('https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<your_alchemy_API_key_here'))
w3.clientVersion
```